# React.JS Function return not returning

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a function called get which fetches data from a local rest api

```
const  get = () => {
    axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        return response;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR', error)
        return error
    })
}
```

Then within App.js i have used the function

```
  useEffect(() =>{
    const response = Data.get();
    console.log(response)
    setPersons(response.data)
  }, []);
```

The `console.log(response)` within the get function is returning the rest api data while the `useEffect()` is logging undefined
Anybody have any idea why it is not returning the same?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a return statement in the `get()` function. It should look like this:

```
const get = () => {
    return axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        return response;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR', error)
        return error
    })
}
```

That will cause `Data.get()` to return the Promise from axios.

You'll then need to wait for the returned Promise to resolve before you can log it from App.js.

You can do that with a `.then`:

```
 useEffect(() =>{
    Data.get()
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        setPersons(response.data)
      });
  }, []);
```

Or an async function:

```
  useEffect(async () =>{
    const response = await Data.get();
    console.log(response)
    setPersons(response.data)
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The axios request is asynchronous.  After you call `Data.get` the code continues onto the next line without waiting for the response.  You could fix this by allowing your `get` function to accept a callback.  Something like this:

```
const  get = (success, error) => {
    axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        success(response)
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log('ERROR', e)
        error(e)
    })
}
```

```
useEffect(() =>{
    Data.get(({data}) => setPersons(data), (error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);
```